# Computing multiple averages in a table with multiple different conditions

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm trying to compute average for multiple columns in my table and I'm trying to impose rules to calculate this average based on a where clause. Since I do not have distinct values on most of these columns, I am unable to do a group by clause to get the correct results. A simple where clause with all the conditions does not compute the average correctly. Is there a workaround for this problem?

My table looks like

```
col1  col2  col3  col4
0     -3     0     109
3      2    -1     -108
-4    -1     3      3
2      0     4      2
2      1    107    -2
```

My intention here is to compute avg for each column based on a rule. For ex:avg(col1) should include values between 0 and 100, avg(col2) should include values between -1 to -100, avg(col3) should include values between 0 and 100,
avg(col4) should include values between -1 to -100.

```
select avg(col1), avg(col2), avg(col3), avg(col4) from tbl1
where (col1 between 0 and 100) and (col1 between -1 and -100) and (col3 between 0 and 100) and (col4 between -1 and -100)
```

Comment: So compute the average of the values meeting the where condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution should accomplish your objectives. First, we use some CTE (subqueries) to just limit the values in the columns to what we want, then we get their averages.

```
WITH
    first_col AS
        (
            SELECT col1
            FROM the_table
            WHERE col1 >= 0 and col1 <= 100
        ),

    second_col AS
        (
            SELECT col2
            FROM the_table
            WHERE col2 >= -100 and col2 <= -1
        ),

    third_col AS
        (
            SELECT col3
            FROM the_table
            WHERE col3 >= 0 and col3 <= 100
        ),

    fourth_col AS
        (
            SELECT col4
            FROM the_table
            WHERE col4 >= -100 and col4 <= -1
        )

    SELECT
        AVG(first_col.col1),
        AVG(second_col.col2),
        AVG(third_col.col3),
        AVG(fourth_col.col4)

    FROM
        first_col,
        second_col,
        third_col,
        fourth_col
```

You can look at [this SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/672fb/2) for the result.

```
1   -2  2   -2
```

Alternatively, you can use this query to avoid using `CTE`

```
SELECT
AVG(CASE WHEN col1 >= 0 AND col1 <= 100 THEN col1 END) AS col1avg,
AVG(CASE WHEN col2 >= -100 AND col2 <= -1 THEN col2 END) AS col2avg,
AVG(CASE WHEN col3 >= 0 AND col3 <= 100 THEN col3 END) AS col3avg,
AVG(CASE WHEN col4 >= -100 AND col4 <= -1 THEN col4 END) AS col4avg
FROM
the_table
```

And you can see the results on [this SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/672fb/10)

```
1   -2  2   -2
```

- Note - This does assume you want the values inclusive, since the `BETWEEN` statement is inclusive.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But is there a way to do this without having to create multiple CTE's?

Comment: Is there an issue with the above method? Given the data, it solves the problem efficiently and in < 50 SLOC

Comment: I have added a version without using `CTE` @Karam

Comment: Glad to hear it helped! @Karam